# PHP returns not found on binary file exec

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm trying to implement the script call to a binary file on script access.
So, the problem is that instead of executing a file, php reports an error: not found.

This is the code of script:
    $plugin_name = "sounds";

```
$cmd = "./spcomp $plugin_name.sp -o $plugin_name.smx";
shell_exec($cmd);
if(is_resource("$path_to_compiler/$plugin_name.smx")) { echo "success"; }
```

**spcomp** is located next to **sounds.sp** (php script aswell) (these are [sourcemod](http://www.sourcemod.net/downloads.php) files btw, you need the linux branch if you want to look inside). I can execute these files separately, but not using php.
This is what I get when script is trying to exec $cmd:
`[Sat Aug 01 11:24:19 2015] [error] [client *.*.*.*] sh: 1: ./spcomp: not found`
sh is the working folder.
The bin isn't corrupted, it is 775 and I am able to run it via terminal.

So, what's wrong with it?

Tried:

- all sorts of shell execution
- absolute paths
- cwd change
- different functions (the same result)
- shebang for the $cmd

And nothing of this worked.

Thank you.

Comment: "Not found" has nothing to do with corruption or anything. It simply means the file is not there. Your processes working directory is not what you expect. Note that `shell_exec()` performs a shell execution. I suggest you try a `cwd` to find out the current working directory that is chosen if you run a shell execution. It depends on your http server account setup. Alternatively you can simply use the absolute path of that file `spcomp`.

Comment: @arkascha I tried absolute paths and chdir. This time, php and bin are located in the same dir named sh.
None of those ways worked aswell.

Comment: "Does not work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to solve a problem. Please be _precise_. What error exactly did you get with those tries? If it really was the same error, then you have a different issue: then that file simply is not located where you would expect it or your system sets up an environment for your shell that uses another file system. Maybe an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = `svn cat ....`

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($filename));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 

echo $test;
```